Experimental Japanese Film which tells three short stories
I remember watching a Japanese film which told three short stories. Two of them I remember, which the other one I forget completely:
The film opens with a man running. He is running away from armed men. He eventually runs to the top of a building, where there is a woman contemplating suicide. They both jump, and end up landing in a truck filled with feathers.
The other scene I remember is an armed standoff between two men dressed in old fashioned clothing (old fashioned as in America, 1930's) with no dialogue and barely any sound effects, aside from saxophone music, shot in black and white.
If anyone can identify this, that would be fantastic.

Was it animated? Roughly when was it released, or otherwise when did you watch it and what do you estimate was its release year? Add as much detail as possible when asking identify questions.

It was live action, i'd say it was within the 2000-2010 time frame.

After quite a lot of prodding and asking friends, I managed to figure out the movie is:
Dead End Run (2003), directed by Sogo Ishii!


Dead End Run is a 2003 film directed by Japanese cult film director Sogo Ishii, notable for Ishii's trademark flashy visual style.
The film has little plot to speak of, but is instead divided into three short episodes, each of which opens with a man desperately running away before being trapped in a dead end, where something out-of-the-ordinary occurs. The episodes include a musical number, a Mexican stand-off and a police pursuit.
—"Dead End Run", Wikipedia

Thanks.

Thanks for posting the answer once you found the film.  Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.
